# Badbox in bibiliography while using TexnicCenter

Tags: spacing, bibtex, bibliographies

I have the following excerpt from my bibliography and it is spaced as expected and produces no problems except for one citation, namely `\bibitem{Mulmuley}`.

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{McMullen} P. McMullen (1970), The maximum number of faces of a convex polytope, Mathematika 17,179--184.

\bibitem{Mulmuley} K. Mulmuley (1994), Computational Geometry: An Introduction Through Randomized Algorithms. Prentice- Hall, Englewood Cliffs, NJ.

\bibitem{SavaniStengel} R. Savani and B. von Stengel (2004), Exponentially many steps for finding a Nash equilibrium in a bimatrix game. CDAM Research Report LSE-CDAM-2004-03.
```

Every time I compile it, I get a bad box pointing to that line. You can see the spacing going astray for that particular citation in the image below.

[image]

Any suggestions about how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The word `Through` is unbreakable, so you can neglect the warning. There are also two typos in your bibliography: no space after `17,` in [8] and Space after `Prentice-` in [9].

Comment: Thanks for pointing those typos out. What do you mean by the word Through is unbreakable? Also, there seem to be a lot of extra spaces between words in [9]. How do I fix that?

Comment: "unbreakable" means "there is no legitimate hyphenation point in this word, so it must be complete on a single line".  since "through" doesn't fit on the first line, it it carried complete to the second line, and the only way to justify the first line is to stretch the spaces.  the spaces are stretched beyond a certain predefined amount, which is the reason for the underfull hbox message.